# How to insert solid color images into photo library collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I already implemented code which shows photo library images in my `UICollectionView` but I really want my 6th 7th and 12th cell to be solid color. Is it possible to achieve? Basically I need somehow to insert cells and don't broke my code which inserts images from photo library.

Like this:
[image]

My code:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photocell", for: indexPath) as! AlbumCollectionViewCell
        cell.image.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.image.clipsToBounds = true
        let asset = images[indexPath.row]
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        if cell.tag != 0 {
                manager.cancelImageRequest(PHImageRequestID(cell.tag))
            }
        cell.tag = Int(manager.requestImage(for: asset,
                                            targetSize: CGSize(width: 250.0, height: 250.0),
                                                contentMode: .aspectFill,
                                                options: nil) { (result, _) in
                                                    cell.image.image = result

            })
        return cell
}
```

I also reverse images array:

```
func getImages() {
    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: nil)
    assets.enumerateObjects({ (object, count, stop) in
       // self.cameraAssets.add(object)
        self.images.append(object)
    })

    //In order to get latest image first, we just reverse the array
    self.images.reverse()

    // To show photos, I have taken a UICollectionView
    self.photosCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you are allowed to have more than one type of cell. So you can have some cells that display images and other cells that display a solid swatch of color. So based on what item this is, instead of saying `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photocell"`, you would say `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "swatchcell"` and you'd configure the swatch instead of configuring the photo.

**EDIT** You added a comment:

> I would like much more to insert new item into my array of images which is [PHAsset] data type

Oh, so now the problem is merely what the *model* for the data should be. That's simple: just use a data type which is an Asset-Or-Color, and make an array of that:

```
enum AssetOrColor {
    case asset(PHAsset)
    case color(UIColor)
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Nice solution if I'm going to put a solid color cell on top of the photo library PHAsset() image (as I understand your answer). I'm going to try this but I would like much more to insert new item into my array of images which is [PHAsset] data type. That's a little bit more complex but that would be perfect for what I'm building. I'm going to clarify my question tommorow. I tried to insert but it's not that easy since the array is PHAsset type. OR maybe I'm totally wrong. Maybe the other solution is somehow to create blank object in array and then set different cell type on top. Idk

Comment: You need a union object, an object which is an Asset-or-Color. That’s easy.

Comment: I created enum AssetOrCollor like you said and my array now looks like this: 'var images = [AssetOrImage]()'. Now I don't get what you meant by saying I need union object. I made a research and found out that there's union() function which is not suitable for me since according to Apple documentation I need to use Set which is perfect if I'm not "concerned with the order of the elements in the collection". But I'm concerned about it. Also, I cannot convert 'PHAsset' to expected argument type 'AssetOrImage' in getImages() function.

Comment: Well, http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECcaseTypedValue

Comment: I recently developed working solution to my problem by myself but I think I would win best bad code practise contest with it (lol). Just created var images = [Any]() and then created another array of different data type and inserted into images array. And when I set cells I just use typeOfItem() function to check datatype. Anyway, I'm going to try understand your solution and try by myself tomorrow.

Comment: Any time you use `[Any]` it's a Bad Smell. What you need is a thing that might be a PHAsset or might be a color and there's a clear and simple and safe way to know which, and that's all it can be. That is the enum. You need to learn basic Swift here.